# C# How convert stream codec G711 to codec ogg or mp3?

Tags: c#, streaming, codec, live-streaming

How convert a stream G711 codec to stream MP3 or OGG? I use LumiSoft.Net dll

I receive the G711  stream like that for the moment:

```
        byte[] decodedData = null;
        if (m_Codec == 0)
        {
            decodedData = G711.Decode_aLaw(e.Data, 0, e.Data.Length);
        }
        else if (m_Codec == 1)
        {
            decodedData = G711.Decode_uLaw(e.Data, 0, e.Data.Length);
        }

        m_pWaveOut.Play(decodedData, 0, decodedData.Length);
```

Thanks

Comment: So what is the question?